Corrcetly ordering snapshot and release versions in Maven vs OSGi/Tycho
In a regular Maven project it's not unusual to create snapshots with a POM version like 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and later make a release for the very same version, like 1.0.0. And Maven will correctly consider 1.0.0 to be newer/later than 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
In Tycho the tycho-versions plugin will essentially replace SNAPSHOT with qualifier for the bundle version which in turn is replaced by a timestamp during the build (per default).
So, assuming versions between POMs and Eclipse/OSGi metadata are consistently synchronized, the snapshot POM version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT results in something like 1.0.0.202406220726 for the final bundle version; and the release version 1.0.0 will be exactly that: 1.0.0.
But OSGi (as far as I'm aware) has no concept of snapshot or release versions. So the snapshot 1.0.0.202406220726 will simply be considered newer than the actual 1.0.0 release. Which is technically correct, but certainly not the desired and expected outcome. And it e.g. prevents people from easily updating an Eclipse plug-in to the actual release if they previously installed the associated snapshot.
While this is only a problem when snapshot and release version are the same (without the qualifier), it still seems common enough that I can't be the only one stumbling over this.
Is there a proper way to handle this? If not, what's the best workaround?
Options I'm so far considering:

Use some even/odd version number pattern for snapshot/release versions.
Don't increase the (snapshot) version after a release, but only before a release. So after releasing 1.0.0 continue development with 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and then release 1.0.1 (I'm ignoring that it could also be 1.1.0 because that's not a problematic case). The resulting bundle versions would be sorted correctly, while the POM versions technically wouldn't. But the POM version is not really important since it's not published anywhere. Seems a bit sketchy, and a versioning like that wouldn't work for bundles that are also used as regular Maven JAR artifacts.
???


OSGi uses semantic versioning, where 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is not a valid version number. In contrast to Maven, in OSGi bundles can be started and stopped and run time so the dependencies have to be resolved not only at compile time, but also at runtime. The concept of snapshot vs. release is not related to the run time and should therefore not be part of the version in OSGi.

@howlger As I explained, the "SNAPSHOT" from the POM is replaced with "qualifier" for the bundle version, which Tycho eventually replaces with a timestamp for the final bundle version during the build. So that's really not the issue here.

Also, according to your linked SemVer specification, 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT actually would be a valid (pre-release) version. But the generated bundle versions from my examples are purely numerical.

In OSGi the qualifier version part is delimited by ., not by - (so it would be 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT instead of 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT). But the point is that a snapshot flag should not be part of the artifact itself. In plain Maven, the version is specified in the pom.xml not required by the artifact itself. In OSGi the version is an important part of the artifact and used at run time. A different version of an artifact can break the application. In OSGi you need to follow semantic versioning.

Not sure how to make it any clearer that 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is not in any way the string that ends up being used as the OSGi bundle version. Maybe you're not familiar with Tycho? What I'm describing is default Tycho behavior where a Maven version is converted into a valid OSGi version, with SNAPSHOT essentially being replaced by a timestamp (see my examples from the question). But where Maven (and SemVer) considers 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT less than 1.0.0, OSGi/Eclipse considers 1.0.0.202406220726 (and other qualifiers) greater than 1.0.0, which is a potential tripping point.

While I'm interested in Tycho specifically, maybe there's a solution from the OSGi angle alone: Even in the world of OSGi there are snapshop or pre-release versions. There may not be an official way to unambiguously differentiate them, but they exist. So if e.g. the target version is 1.0.0, what version would you use for snapshots/pre-releases of that bundle?

The equivalent of a Maven snapshot version is in Tycho publishing the artifacts to a specific repository, in the Eclipse IDE simultaneous release called "staging" (e.g. https://download.eclipse.org/staging/2024-06/ vs. https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-06/). Be aware that in Tycho you can have multiple local (and remote) repositories and you have a target definition file in which you refer those repositories. The fact that in Maven the artifact version has two different aspects is controversial. In OSGi, snapshot versions are clearly a bad idea since it is part of the artifact.
